# Merge output of different tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, select, full-outer-join

I have two tables `t1` and `t2`. I need to merge their output
`t1`

```
 day_hour | col1 
----------+------
 09 AM    |    1
 10 AM    |    3
 11 AM    |    0
 12 PM    |    4
```

`t2`

```
 day_hour | col2 
----------+------
 08 AM    |    11
 11 AM    |    7
 12 PM    |    7
 01 PM    |    6
 02 PM    |    4
```

The output should be

```
 day_hour |   col1  |  col2 
----------+---------+--------
 08 AM    |    NULL |    11
 09 AM    |    1    |    NULL
 10 AM    |    3    |    NULL
 11 AM    |    0    |    7
 12 PM    |    4    |    7
 01 PM    |    NULL |    6
 02 PM    |    NULL |    4
```

So far I have tried `FULL OUTER JOIN`, but that does not give me the merged `day_hour`
Here's my query

```sql
SELECT t1.day_hour, t1.col1, t2.col2
FROM (SELECT day_hour, col1 FROM t1)
FULL OUTER JOIN 
(SELECT day_hour, col1 FROM t2)
ON t1.day_hour = t2.day_hour;
```

I'm using postgres 11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `COALESCE()`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(t1.day_hour, t2.day_hour) day_hour, t1.col1, t2.col2
FROM t1
FULL OUTER JOIN t2 ON t1.day_hour = t2.day_hour;
```

But in Postgres the `USING` join clause comes handy for this:

```
SELECT day_hour, t1.col1, t2.col2
FROM t1
FULL OUTER JOIN t2 USING(day_hour)
```

Note that the subqueries are unnecessary - I remove them.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an UNION

```
    select t.day_hour , t1.col1, t2.col2
    from (
        select day_hour
        from  t1
        union 
        select day_hour
        from  t2

        ) t1
        left join t1 on t1.day_hour = t.day_hour
        left join  t2 on t2.day_hour = t.day_hour
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to coalesce day_hour from the two tables.

```
select
coalesce(t1.day_hour,t2.day_hour),
t1.col1,
t2.col1,
...
```